# C : How to pause sigaction Timer

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

There is one function called test(), I want to call this function in every 30 seconds, Please find my implemented code snippet.

```
void init_sigaction(void) {
    struct sigaction act;    
    act.sa_handler = test; //test()
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGPROF, &act, NULL);
}


void init_time(void) {
    struct itimerval val;
    val.it_value.tv_sec = 30; //Timer 30 Seconds
    val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    val.it_interval = val.it_value;
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &val, NULL);
}

int main()
{
  /*Set the handler for the signal SIG to HANDLER */
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    init_sigaction();
    init_time();

    Some_other_function();

}
```

Now I am using some other function, and I want to pause sigaction timer until other function's execution. how can I implemented interrupt for pause?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to stop the timer from running, or defer the signal handler's execution?

Comment: I want to stop the timer and again when my other processes completed, I want to run timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer) of `setitimer`:

> A timer which is set to zero (it_value is zero or the timer expires and it_interval is zero) stops.

Call `setitimer` with zero times, and with a valid `old_value` argument to store the current values of the timer, so you can start it again later.

**Edit:**

How about something like this:

```
struct itimerval old_timer;

void pause_timer()
{
    struct itimerval zero_timer = { 0 };
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &zero_time, &old_timer);
}

void resume_timer()
{
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &old_timer, NULL);
}
```

**Note** The code above is untested, and coded only by reading the manual page.

Comment: @Nimit Added a couple of simple functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider blocking some signals with e.g. the [sigprocmask(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) system call.

However, I strongly recommend reading several times the [signal(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) man page. Don't forget that a signal handler can happen any time (including at the worst possible time, e.g. during calls to `fprintf` or `malloc`...), so can only call directly or indirectly *async-signal-safe functions*; and a big lot of library functions are not in this small restricted set. A usual way is to set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag in the signal handler, and test for it outside.